# Insert values in multiple entity core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5

I'm trying to insert values in 2 entities. It is possible if I use 2 NSManagedObject, each one set for a different entity, but I was wondering if there's another way to do it - a more elegant way.
Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"Date"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
NSEntityDescription *entity2 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity2" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity2 name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newManagedObject2 setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"Date"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

It works, but I'm not convinced that it is the best way.

Comment: If these are two distinct instances of an NSManagedObject subclass, this would be the correct approach. Set values on each of those instances. Can you post your relavent code to help better illustrate your question?

Comment: sure, i edit the question showing an example